# Cat6 Cable not working with router, only working with Laptop

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, modem, cat6

I just made a Cat6 wire and the order of colors is

orange strip

orange

blue

green strip

blue strip

green

brown strip

brown

This cable on one end is connected to modem and the other end only works when connected to my Laptop and when i try to connect it with my Netgear or D-Link modem, it doesnt work. What can i do? I already tried reseting both the routers. The Dlink router is new

Comment: Have done it like that on both sides? If you have then it should work (even you have not followed the standard - it is always striped, full, striped, full,... just google for RJ45 scheme) - so it could be the problem if you have done one side correctly and the other like you mentioned (striped, full, full, striped,...)

Comment: Could you provide a photo of both ends?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to follow standards otherwise it could very well be your cable and your laptop is just less picky. Could be a dead port and what do you mean by doesnt work? No link, no internet? Your cable should be on o,o/w,g,b/w,b,g/w,br,br/w or swap orange and green which is ok too. Split pairs like you have can cause numerous issues. Fix your cable, then update us.